# How do you tie a String variable to a String variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, if-statement, java.util.scanner

Hello so I am attempting to write a code that test the operators and need a little help declaring variables.
So in my code under my if statement I declare a certain answer to be true or false depending on what the entered number would be and I keep getting stuck on the "cannot find symbol" error. Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestOperators
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //prompt the user to enter an integer
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      int num = input.nextInt();

      String t = new String("True");
      String f = new String("False");

      //calculate
      if ((num % 5 == 0) && (num % 6 == 0))
         answer = t;
      else if ((num % 5 == 0) && (num % 6 != 0) || (num % 5 != 0) && (num % 6 == 0))
         answer = t;
      else if ((num % 5 == 0) || (num % 6 == 0))
         answer = t;
      else
         answer = f;   

   //print results
      System.out.println("Is " + num + " divisible by 5 and 6? " + answer);
      System.out.println("Is " + num + " divisible by 5 or 6?" + answer);
      System.out.print("Is " + num + " divisible by 5 or 6, but not both?" + answer);

   }
}
```

The program tells me that I cannot declare the variable "answer" in that spot. I am trying to tie the string "f" and "t" variables to the answer variable and dont know how. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

You're not *declaring* the variable at all. You're just trying to *assign* to it. You can just add

```
String answer;
```

to the code before you start trying to assign to it.

Additionally, you almost never want to call `new String(String)`, and you can simplify your code significantly. You'd be better off determining the result (e.g. just with `||`) and then converting the result into a string:

```
boolean result = ((num % 5 == 0) && (num % 6 == 0)) ||
                 ((num % 5 == 0) && (num % 6 != 0) || (num % 5 != 0) && (num % 6 == 0)) ||
                 ((num % 5 == 0) || (num % 6 == 0));
String answer = result ? "True" : "False";
```

Looking at that, the result you want *actually* seems to be as simple as:

```
String answer = (num % 5 == 0 || num % 6 == 0) ? "True" : "False";
```

The only way you can get "False" as an answer in both your original code and my final code is if the number isn't divisible by either 5 or 6.

Your code just expresses that in a really complicated way...

Comment: genius solution! but I think this is a bit complicated for beginner

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: Look at the final result - I'd say that's *much* simpler than the original code in the question, wouldn't you?

Comment: yes, correct! the _complicated_ part I mean here is for OP to come with this solution :D

Answer (score 2):

You never declared `answer`. Try adding this line at the beginning of the method:

```
String answer;
```

Comment: and if it is initialized to "False" (as it will need to be initialized), then you do not need the last `else`